# UITextView do not insert line break here

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I have UITextView. It contains some math formulas. 
For example, "In triangle ABC side AB = 5".
Sometimes UITextView breaks line after "=". It becomes like this

*In triangle ABC side AB =*

*5*

But I want "AB = 5" to be together always:

*In triangle ABC side*

*AB = 5*

How can I do it? I don't want delete spaces like "AB=5". Thank you.

Comment: can you go into more detail? Like is it OK for "AB = 5" to be on same line as previous text if possible?

Comment: Yes, it is OK. I want "AB = 5" to be together always.

Comment: Use non-breaking spaces instead of regular spaces in places you don't want wrapping to occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question right, you are looking for `\n` a line break:

```
NSLog(@"In triangle ABC side\nAB = 5")
```

Ok since I understood your intention better, maybe this can be a solution or a start for your solution:

```
- (NSString *) makeStringNonWrappable : (NSString *) string
{
    NSMutableString *myString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:string];
    NSRange rangeValue = [myString rangeOfString:@" = " options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if (rangeValue.length > 0){
        NSLog(@"string contains  =  %d %d", rangeValue.location, rangeValue.length);
        NSString *nonbreakingspace = @"\u00A0";
        NSString * replacementString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", nonbreakingspace, nonbreakingspace];
        [myString replaceCharactersInRange:rangeValue withString:replacementString];

        NSLog(@"%@", myString);
        return myString;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"string does not contain = !");
        return string;
    }
}
```

Basically, I find the `=` occurance in your String and replace it with a string which looks exactly same but is processed different by the `UITextView`. the spaces are not processed as spaces anymore. Note, i didnt compile the code there might be some typos..

Comment: I think he wants a more general solution: never break lines between "name and assigment".

Comment: try new solution please

Comment: It is awesome! Thank you very much! :) Now I know about unbreakable spaces.